# Scale Html List based on resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a `<ul>` containing a series of elements, they are formatted with CSS so they form a half donut chart.
I want to make this mobile-friendly so the content scales along with the screen.

I have tried to used media queries to change the width, and height of the elements and also the border-radius size with no success.

```css
    
    body {
      font: normal 16px/1.5 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      padding: 130px 0 0 0;
      background: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    /* RESET STYLES
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
    
    .chart-skills {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .chart-skills *,
    .chart-skills::before {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    /* CHART-SKILLS STYLES
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
    
    .chart-skills {
      position: relative;
      width: 800px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    
    .chart-skills::before,
    .chart-skills::after {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .chart-skills::before {
      content: '';
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
      border: 45px solid rgba(211, 211, 211, .3);
      border-bottom: none;
      border-top-left-radius: 400px;
      border-top-right-radius: 400px;
    }
    
    .chart-skills::after {
      content: 'Low to High Risk';
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 10px;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #009933;
    }
    
    .chart-skills li {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
      border: 45px solid;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 400px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 400px;
      transform-origin: 50% 0;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: .1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(1) {
      z-index: 19;
      border-color: #00FF00;
      animation-name: rotate-1;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(2) {
      z-index: 18;
      border-color: #24FF00;
      animation-name: rotate-2;
      animation-delay: .1s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(3) {
      z-index: 17;
      border-color: #47FF00;
      animation-name: rotate-3;
      animation-delay: .2s;
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(4) {
      z-index: 16;
      border-color: #58FF00;
      animation-name: rotate-4;
      animation-delay: .3s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(5) {
      z-index: 15;
      border-color: #6AFF00;
      animation-name: rotate-5;
      animation-delay: .4s;
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(6) {
      z-index: 14;
      border-color: #8DFF00;
      animation-name: rotate-6;
      animation-delay: .6s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(7) {
      z-index: 13;
      border-color: #B0FF00;
      animation-name: rotate-7;
      animation-delay: .7s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(8) {
      z-index: 12;
      border-color: #D4FF00;
      animation-name: rotate-8;
      animation-delay: .8s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(9) {
      z-index: 11;
      border-color: #F7FF00;
      animation-name: rotate-9;
      animation-delay: .9s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(10) {
      z-index: 10;
      border-color: #FFF600;
      animation-name: rotate-10;
      animation-delay: 1s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(11) {
      z-index: 9;
      border-color: #FFE400;
      animation-name: rotate-11;
      animation-delay: 1.1s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(12) {
      z-index: 8;
      border-color: #FFD300;
      animation-name: rotate-12;
      animation-delay: 1.2s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(13) {
      z-index: 7;
      border-color: #FFAF00;
      animation-name: rotate-13;
      animation-delay: 1.3s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(14) {
      z-index: 6;
      border-color: #FF8C00;
      animation-name: rotate-14;
      animation-delay: 1.4s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(15) {
      z-index: 5;
      border-color: #FF6900;
      animation-name: rotate-15;
      animation-delay: 1.5s;
    
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(16) {
      z-index: 4;
      border-color: #FF4600;
      animation-name: rotate-16;
      animation-delay: 1.6s;
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(17) {
      z-index: 3;
      border-color: #FF2300;
      animation-name: rotate-17;
      animation-delay: 1.7s;
    }
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(18) {
      z-index: 2;
      border-color: #FF1100;
      animation-name: rotate-18;
      animation-delay: 1.8s;
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(19) {
      z-index: 1;
      border-color: #FF0000;
      animation-name: rotate-19;
      animation-delay: 1.9s;
    }
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    @keyframes rotate-1{
      100% {
        transform: rotate(9.5deg);
      }
    }
     
    @keyframes rotate-2{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(9.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(19deg);
      }
    }
     
    @keyframes rotate-3{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(19deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(28.5deg);
      }
    }
     
    @keyframes rotate-4{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(28.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(38deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes rotate-5{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(38deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(47.5deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-6{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(47.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(57deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-7{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(57deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(66.5deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-8{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(66.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(76deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-9{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(76deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(85.5deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-10{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(85.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(95deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-11{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(95deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(104.5deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-12{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(104.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(114deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-13{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(114deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(123.5deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-14{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(123.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(133deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-15{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(133deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(142.5deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-16{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(142.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(152deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-17{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(152deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(161.5deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-18{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(161.5deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(171deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes rotate-19{
      0% {
        transform: rotate(171deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
    }
    
    
    
    .chart-skills span {
      position: absolute;
      font-size: .85rem;
    }
    
    
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(1) span {
      top: 20px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(-9.5deg);
    }
     
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(2) span {
      top: -5px;
      left: 2px;
      transform: rotate(-19deg);
    }
     
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(3) span {
      top: 10px;
      left: 0px;
      transform: rotate(-28.5deg);
    }
     
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(4) span {
      top: 60px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(-38deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(5) span {
      top: 45px;
      left: 0px;
      transform: rotate(-47.5deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(6) span {
      top: 50px;
      left:  0px;
      transform: rotate(-57deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(7) span {
      top: 55px;
      left: -5px;
      transform: rotate(-66.5deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(8) span {
      top: 5px;
      left: -10px;
      transform: rotate(-76deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(9) span {
      top: 105px;
      left: 5px;
      transform: rotate(-85.5deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(10) span {
      top: 15px;
      left: -35px;
      transform: rotate(-95deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(11) span {
      top: -25px;
      left: -25px;
      transform: rotate(-104.5deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(12) span {
      top: -40px;
      left: -10px;
      transform: rotate(-114deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(13) span {
      top: -75px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(-123.5deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(14) span {
      top: 35px;
      left: -5px;
      transform: rotate(-133deg);
    }
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(15) span {
      top: -25px;
      left: -5px;
      transform: rotate(-142.5deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(16) span {
      top: -15px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(-152deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(17) span {
      top: -10px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(-161.5deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(18) span {
      top: 0px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(-171deg);
    }
    
    .chart-skills li:nth-child(19) span {
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
    @keyframes fade-in {
      0%,
      90% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
```

```html
    <ul class="chart-skills">
      <li><span>US savings bonds</span></li>
      <li><span>Savings accounts, money market accounts and CDs</span></li>
      <li><span>US Treasury bills, notes and bonds</span></li>
      <li><span>Annuities</span></li>
      <li><span>Money market funds</span></li>
      <li><span>Municipal bonds</span></li>
      <li><span>Corporate bonds</span></li>
      <li><span>High-yield</span></li>
      <li><span>REITs and MLPs</span></li>
      <li><span>Rental real estate</span></li>
      <li><span>Preferred stock</span></li>
      <li><span>Index funds</span></li>
      <li><span>Mutual funds</span></li>
      <li><span>Large-cap stocks</span></li>
      <li><span>Mid-cap stocks</span></li>
      <li><span>Small-cap stocks</span></li>
      <li><span>Commodities</span></li>
      <li><span>Options</span></li>
      <li><span>Futures</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please consider posting a minimal, reproducible example. In your CSS I can't find any media queries so it's hard to find your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only viable option I see for this is to make this object as an inline SVG element and just scale it. The problem is that it won't be really responsive, it would just scale in terms of size, making the font size really small for smaller screens.

The problem here is the rotation of the elements, because if you reduce the size of the container it gets completely out of place and you'd have to use a lot of conditions for it to work even remotely close to what is desired.

You could make the image as a vector, export the code and just manipulate the text items. After that you just add `width: 100%; height: auto` to the `svg` element and it fits its parent element.

The problem here is that it has way too many elements to be readable in a cell phone. You should consider using an alternative layout for smaller screens.

Comment: I agree with the amount of content being way too much for a typical mobile view. But... That's a UX problem not so much of a code problem.

Comment: I'd change the layout to rows for tablet or below. Something like a structure of color rectangle followed by text to the right. And use the current structure on devices above  800px width. The original question was how to make it responsive, but it would be difficult with that much info as said before.

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest solution in a case like this, is to use a different sizing unit like `rem`. Rem is a relative unit based on the **root** font size instead of the parent size like `em`. So whatever is defined as the Body font size will impact all rem sizes.

What's cool is that, you can also use rem based sizes for `width`, `height`, `padding`, `box-shadow`, `border` and so on. This means when you change the base size EVERYTHING using rem units will resize.

A typical setup looks like this:

**This is important to get an easily understood base size**

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /* uses browser base size (16px) to make 1rem = 10px for easy math! */
}
```

Then in your other CSS change everything you want to scale to be rem based. (I'm simplifying quite a bit here)

```
.chart-skills {

      width: 80rem;
      height: 40rem;
    }
.chart-skills::before {
      border: 4.5rem solid rgba(211, 211, 211, .3);
      border-top-left-radius: 40rem;
      border-top-right-radius: 40rem;
    }

.chart-skills::after {
      bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .chart-skills li {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 40rem;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 40rem;
      /* I might make the border radius 50% instead if that's easier */
    }
```

Then in the media query simply change the `body{ font-size: xx%}` to something that scales correctly.